# How can i see my files on remote Jupyter server? (Vscode)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vscode-remote

I want to use vscode on my computer using remote jupyter connection.
I applied the steps for the connection, i can create a new notebook and run on this remote server.
Bu i want to see my folders on remote server. I want to edit them or create a new file in this server.

[image: vscode]

How can i see this files on my vscode like in jupyterlab?

[image: editor]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Remote - SSH` extension in VS code.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34653369)